# SQLite - ошибка database file is locked

Tags: android, sqlite, таблицы

Такая проблема - немогу извлечь данные из бд, выдает ошибку

```
Caused By : The database file is locked.
```

База хранится отдельным файлом, т.е.  не создается программно. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Если вам дам исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас скорей всего больше одного подключения к базе. Как правило, эта ошибка возникает именно в этом случае.